# How can I "translate" what's going on in this list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I was doing some exercises on list comprehensions and the usage of `*` . I think I know that it's going on, but I find it very difficult to put into concrete words. How would you explain `b`?

I'm not sure how to understand either what the empty string does or what the `(7-i)` causes in b.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
b = [' ' * 2 * (7 - i) + 'very' * i for i in a]
for line in b:
    print(line)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you looked at the output? There's no empty string here; `' '` is a string containing a space.

Answer (score 1):

Your list comprehension takes every element `i` (in this case, they are all integers) from list `a` and then stores the value of `' ' * 2 * (7 - i) + 'very' * i` as an element in the new list `b`.

When multiplying a string with an integer `i`, the string is repeated `i` times. So in your case, `' ' * 2 * (7 - i)` means that a space (not an empty string!) is repeated `2 * (7 - i)` times. For instance, for the second element `i = 2`, this means `2 * (7 - 2) = 10` spaces.

So the second part is `'very' * i` and works the same way. For example, the second element `i = 2`, the string `'very'` is repeated twice.

When adding two strings, they are concatenated. So your second element now has 10 spaces and twice the word `'very'` --> `'          veryvery'`.

Do the same for every other number in `a` and you got

```
b = [
 '            very',
 '          veryvery',
 '        veryveryvery',
 '      veryveryveryvery',
 '    veryveryveryveryvery',
 '  veryveryveryveryveryvery',
 'veryveryveryveryveryveryvery',
 '  veryveryveryveryveryvery',
 '    veryveryveryveryvery',
 '      veryveryveryvery',
 '        veryveryvery',
 '          veryvery',
 '            very']
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for your detailed explanation! I got it now, I'll try doing some more exercises.

Comment: Quick question, so, how would I go about wanting 'very' to be added twice, for example. Let me explain: in the example I have  + 'very' * i for i in a . Which adds 1, 2, 3, 4 'very' after the empty spaces. What if I wanted the number of 'very' to be doubled every time (2 instead of 1, 4 instead of 2, etc.), would I be able to write it like: b = [' ' * 2 * (7 - i) +  'very' * (i*2) i for i in a] ?

Comment: @emdv Yes, this will work if you delete the `i` before `for`: `[' ' * 2 * (7 - i) + 'very' * (i*2) for i in a]`. 
As a tip for quickly checking small things like this you can just use the python interpreter directly from the command line (type `python3` in a terminal window).

Answer (score 1):

Let's split the statement up into its separate parts:

```
b = [' ' * 2 * (7 - i) + 'very' * i for i in a]
```

The looping part is the last part:

```
for i in a
```

This only says that we should loop over the values of `a`, and do the rest of the statement for each entry.

```
' ' * 2 * (7 - i) + 'very' * i
```

This is the actual statement being executed for each value in `a`. In both cases this is a string being multiplied -- which means it's being repeated the number of times it gets multiplied:

```
' ' * 2 * (7 - i)
```

This repeats a single space `2 * (7 - i)` times; which means that it adds between 0 (`2 * (7 - 7)`) and 12 (`2 * (7 - 1)`) spaces in front of the string. The reason why they multiply by `2` is because the string `very` is four characters, so to center it you'll need `length / 2` spaces in front of it.

```
'very' * i
```

This means `very` gets repeated `i` times, which will be `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. times.

The `+` merges the two strings, so that you get [0, 12] spaces, then `very` repeated n times.

When `i` is 1:

- `' ' * 2 * (7 - 1)` => 12 spaces
- `very * 1` => `very`

```
            very
```

If i is 2, the number of spaces decrease by 2 (7 - 2 is now 5), while `very` gets repeated one additional time (`veryvery`):

```
          veryvery
```

Comment: Amazing explanation, thank you for taking the time to help me. I was getting stuck on the 2 * (7 - i) part. THANK YOU !!

Comment: Question : Your wrote "The reason why they multiply by 2 is because the string 'very' is four characters", if I were to try this with a different word, how would I know how to center it? This might be an easy/obvious question but, does IDLE have a specific number of characters lengthwise as if were a piece of graph paper?

Comment: `len(word)` gives you the length of the word, you can then divide this by 2 to get the required offset (`len('very') / 2 == 2`). How to handle this when the number of characters in the number is odd is an exercise left up to the reader :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the list comprehension with a for-loop:

```
b=[]
for i in a:
    nextline = ' ' * 2 * (7 - i) + 'very' * i
    b.append(nextline)
```

What the comprehension is doing is essentially adding whitespace to the beginning, depending on `i`.

You can replace this: `' ' * 2` with this: `'  '` (two spaces) and still get the same result.
Essentially the `(7-i)` is displaying a certain number of whitespace characters for whatever `i` actually is.

Comment: OHHH !! Thank you so much for the for-loop explanation. That made it clearer! Also I  just realized I wasn't understanding that it was adding whitespace to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

So basically here is what is going on step by step:

```
b = [' ' * 2 * (7 - i) + 'very' * i for i in a]
```

`i` is changing values from while going through a : so it has the value 1, then 2 and so on

For the case for example where `i` has the value `1`, the following string is constructed :
two white spaces `" " + " "` 7-1 times (so basically 12 white spaces
then we concatenate `very` 1 time (i times)

Comment: Ahhh! I see, yeah, somehow the part with the ' '  was really confusing, thank you !!